# In Google DataStore GQL, how can I group the WHERE terms?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

I need to group terms in the WHERE clause. For example,

```
WHERE (param1='foo1' OR param1='foo2') AND (param2='bar1' OR param2='bar2')
```

But it's giving me a syntax error saying that the parentheses are "unexpected". The actual error is:

```
GQL query error: Encountered "(" at line 1, column 29. Was expecting one of: "false", "null", "true", <INTEGER>, <DOUBLE>, <SINGLE_QUOTE_STRING>, <DOUBLE_QUOTE_STRING>, <UNQUOTED_NAME>, <QUOTED_NAME>, <NAME_BINDING_SITE>, <POSITION_BINDING_SITE>
```

So, is there any way for me to run that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you're facing comes from the `OR` operator - GQL doesn't have one, so the conditions you have in the paranthesis are syntactically incorrect.

From the `WHERE` row in the [Clauses](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#clauses) table (emphasis mine):

> Limits the result set to those entities that meet one or more
>   conditions. Each condition compares a property of the entity with a
>   value using a comparison operator. If multiple conditions are combined
>   with the **AND** keyword, then an entity must meet all of the
>   conditions to be returned by the query. **GQL does not have an OR
>   operator**.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize that. The error is definitely from having the parentheses in there -- that's what their error message actually says. But since they don't allow the OR, then there really isn't any reason to have the parentheses in the first place

Comment: But is there any way to "simulate" the OR operator? What do I do if I need to find any records that match one of two (or more values)?

Comment: You'd have to make separate queries and combine the results.