# How to get multiple entities using gql in datastore with Or Condition

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

Use OR or IN with datastore

Here is my query i am running to fetch entities

```
    SELECT  * From Transactions
    Where  
      __key__ = Key(Transactions,"00043b75-37f5-49c1-a104-4ebbe3f53a1atuzzin") OR
      __key__ = Key(Transactions,"c0f6a0ff-97b4-42a1-8a16-5473991834c8tuzzin")
```

But `OR` is not supported and `IN` gives error

What is the perfect way to get output?

Entity Meta

```
 - Namespace:  [default]
 - Kind:  Transactions
 - Key:  Transactions 
 - name: dummytranasction-id-string
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `Key(Transactions,"00043b75-37f5-49c1-a104-4ebbe3f53a1atuzzin"` or  `KeyTransactions,"c0f6a0ff-97b4-42a1-8a16-5473991834c8tuzzin)`? The error says that it has found a `"("` so maybe is the second option

Comment: Actully i tried out every combination on upper query but not working. I am editing question.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a 'dummy' example of the kind you are querying, so I can create some and the query them?

Comment: I have created this small example https://pastebin.com/R9zYrigj Do you think you can adapt it to your case? Tell me if it works. We cannot use OR as per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#python_gql_for_app_engine_differences). The example is based on this snippet https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859110/in-google-datastore-gql-how-can-i-group-the-where-terms/49862969#49862969

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez Yes , It worked , I done it in golang. But still i was looking if there is any way we can done this with just gql.

Comment: As of today, `OR` is not supported in GQL, see the first item here https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#python_gql_for_app_engine_differences. Plase post your golang solution as an answer, it would be of great benefit to the community. I am glad you solved the issue

Comment: I added an answer. Feel free to add the `Golang` example and update the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot use `OR` in `GQL` as [per the docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference#python_gql_for_app_engine_differences). You can get the entities if you know the keys for example:

```
from google.cloud import datastore
import google.cloud.exceptions

def batch_lookup(client):

    keys = [
            client.key('Transactions', "00043b75-37f5-49c1-a104-4ebbe3f53a1atuzzin"),
            client.key('Transactions', "c0f6a0ff-97b4-42a1-8a16-5473991834c8tuzzin")
            ]

    result_set = []

    for i in range(len(keys)):
        key = keys[i]
        t = client.get(key)
        if t is not None:
            result_set.append(t)
            print(str(i + 1) + ": " + str(t))

    return result_set

datastore_client = datastore.Client()

batch_lookup(datastore_client)
```

This example uses the snippet mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#datastore-datastore-lookup-python)