# Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Identifier at symbol (

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I am trying to get a result using an optional parameters.

```
result = Tester.gql("WHERE (first_name IS NULL OR first_name = :first_name)"
                                "AND (last_name IS NULL OR last_name = :last_name)"
                                "AND (birth_date IS NULL OR birth_date = :birth_date)"
                                "AND (test_voucher IS NULL OR test_voucher = :test_voucher)", first_name=first_name,
                                last_name=last_name, birth_date=birth_date, test_voucher=test_voucher)
```

However, I am getting an error about parsing when I use this GQL script.

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Parse Error: Invalid WHERE Identifier at symbol ("
    }
}
```

I am trying to figure out what is wrong in my GQL script. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's valid GQL:

- there is no mentioning of using '(' and ')' for compound conditions (which is what I belive the error you see is about), the only valid condition constructs are (from [GQL Reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference)):

  ```
  [ WHERE <compound-condition> ]

  <compound-condition> := <condition>+AND

  <condition> :=
    <property-name> IS NULL
  | <property-name> <forward-comparator> <value>
  | <value> <backward-comparator> <property-name>
  ```
- there is no `OR` operator in GQL, so there is no need for grouping, see [In Google DataStore GQL, how can I group the WHERE terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859110/in-google-datastore-gql-how-can-i-group-the-where-terms/49862969#49862969) (also complaining about parentheses)